# с++: возвращение типа, а не переменной

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, типы-данных, typedef

Подскажите (что-то не могу найти, хотя точно помню, что такая элементарная вещь в C++ была) как вернуть не переменную, а ее тип, который я дальше могу использовать в шаблонах и `sizeof()`

т.е. что-то типа

```
class myClass
{
    public:
        struct myData
        {};

        static typedef type() {
            return myData;
        }
}
```

с использованием

```
std::vector<myClassObject::type()> data;
```

P.S.

кстати а почему я не могу объявить константный статический метод?

```
static typedef type() const;
```

выдает ошибку

Comment: Константный статик метод вам нужен чтобы в нем запретить изменения других статик полей?

Comment: Vladimir Gamalyan, именно так (это не критично для моей задачи, но стало интересно)

Comment: Явная XY-проблема. В С++ нет такого понятия, как "возвращение типа". Опишите подробнее, что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: "константный статический метод" - это бессмыслица. Потому и выдает ошибку. Что вы хотели этим достичь?

Comment: Ant, вот задача целиком: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/886815/c-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0-%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5

Comment: Ant, по поводу статического метода - хотел добиться минимальной необходимости - если метод класса не изменяет членов класса, он должен быть константным :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Язык С++ - строго типизированный, так что во время выполнения такое не делается, только во время компиляции. А тут все просто - например,

```
class myClass
{
    public:
        struct myData
        {};

        using type = myData;
};


vector<myClass::type> data;

myClass object;

vector<decltype(object)::type> obj_data;
```

Ну, а второй вопрос (кстати, ну не надо разнотипные вопросы в один объединять) - так а к чему ваше `const` должно относиться? Объекта-то у статической функции нет... Вас же не удивляет, что вы не можете объявить константную функцию, которая не изменяет глобальные переменные? :)

Comment: Harry, просто если есть статическая переменная в классе и есть метод `get` который ее только выдает, но не меняет, как то ожидаешь, что его можно сделать константным, чтобы под горячую руку эту переменную не изменить :)

Comment: Harry, касательно "...такое не делается, только во время компиляции..." - это то как раз и нужно, хотя у меня начинает складываться, что я или что-то не то делаю или микроскопом начинаю забивать гвозди :), но об этом я еще пост/вопрос напишу :) (просто у меня шаблон `template <class T1, class T2>`, но при этом `T2` используется и `T1`, поэтому подумалось, что можно сократить запись до `template<class T>` и от `T` потребовать просто метода `type()`

Comment: Ну, тогда изложите исходную задачу...

Comment: Harry, вот изложил - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/886815/c-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0-%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5

Answer (score 0):

А зачем усложнять?

```
class myClass
{
    //
public:    
    struct myData {};
    //...
};

std::vector<typename myClass::myData > v;
```

После того, как вы отправили ссыльку на задачу.
Допустим имеем:

```
struct CDataCompact { ... };

class CDataCompactParser {
   static CDataCompact d;
public:
    static CDataCompact get_data()  { return d; }

    //...
};
CDataCompact  CDataCompactParser::d = CDataCompact();
```

Чтобы статический метод возвращал обьект данного типа, класс должен иметь статический обьект этого типа.  (Выше указан случай, если структура обьявлена в классе).

Дальше, если вы обьявляете шаблонный класс с двумя аргументами шаблона, то вы никак не сможете потом инстанцировать с одним аргументом.

```
template<class IExtractor, class IData>
class CExtractor
{
  //...
};
```

Другое дело, если вы определите другой шаблонный класс :

```
template<class T, class V = decltype(T::get_data()) >
class CExtractor_1 {... } ;
```

Или

```
template<class T> class
        CExtractor_1 : public CExtractor<T, decltype(T::get_data()) >{};
```

Тогда вы легко можете использовать `CExtractor_1<CDataCompactParser>` вмеcто  `CExtractor<CDataCompactParser, CDataCompact>`

Comment: просто целиком задача у меня выглядит так: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/886815/c-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0-%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5  и я стараюсь ее по чуть-чуть решить, но пока не получается :(