# c++ реализация контейнера с итератором для доступа к данным, хранящимся в файле

Tags: c++, наследование, шаблоны-с++, типы-данных

Поскольку когда мучаю читателей этого сайта мелкими задачами и часто возникает вопрос "зачем", то решил описать сразу и большую задачу, с которой и вожусь:

У меня есть данные (в виде файла или группы файлов), которые в бинарном виде содержат последовательность структурированных блоков (можно сказать, что содержат некоторый вектор). Эти файлы огромные (100ГБ..1ТБ), поэтому вычитать их целиком в память я не могу.

При этом:

1) есть файлы, содержащие данные одного типа `CDataFull`, а есть файлы, содержащие другой тип данных `CDataCompact` (я их использую для разных задач, в одном просто больше данных хранится, но данные те же)

2) работа с данными происходит последовательно

Поскольку программа у меня наращивалась постепенно, то появились функции, которые по сути делают одно и тоже, но с разными данными. И поэтому мне захотелось переписать это красиво и компактно.

Сейчас код выглядит примерно так:

```
bool Process(const std::wstring& path)
{
    // получить доступ к файлу с данными и определить его характеристики
    HANDLE inputFile = ::CreateFile(path.c_str(), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    if (inputFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return false;

    _i64 fileSize = 0;
    const BOOL isGetted = ::GetFileSizeEx(inputFile, (PLARGE_INTEGER)&fileSize);

    // выделить память для хранения данных
    const _i64 bufferSize = sizeof(CDataCompact) * _BUFFER_RECORDS_AMOUNT_;
    char* buffer = new char[bufferSize];

    // обработать данные
    while (true)
    {
        // считать кусок файла
        DWORD readedBytes = 0;
        const BOOL isReaded = ::ReadFile(inputFile, buffer, (DWORD)bufferSize, &readedBytes, NULL);

        if (readedBytes == 0)
            break;

        // последовательно проанализировать записи, записанные в буфер
        const _i64 recordsAmount = readedBytes / sizeof(CDataCompact);

        for (int recordIndex = 0; recordIndex < recordsAmount; recordIndex++)
        {
            // распарсить
            CData data = parse(buffer + recordIndex * sizeof(CDataCompact));

            // обработать данные
            ProcessData(data);
        }
    }

    // освободить память
    delete[] buffer;

    // освободить файл с данными
    ::CloseHandle(inputFile);

    return true;
}
```

Ну WinAPI работу с файлом я заменил уже на `std::ifstream` для однообразия (чтоб STL повсюду).

И решил сделать так, чтобы всю обработку можно было бы реализовать через единый шаблонный класс и итератор, т.е. чтоб выглядело все так:

```
bool Process(const std::wstring& path)
{
    CExtractor<CDataCompact> extractor(path);

    for (CExtractor<CDataCompact>::const_iterator it = extractor.begin(); it != extractor.end(); it++)
    {
        // обработать данные
        ProcessData(*it);
    }

    extractor.close();

    return true;
}
```

Маппить файл тут не вариант - медленная работа да и все равно на него будет нужна обвеска, поэтому решил все свое :)

Т.е. нужно было бы сделать несколько вещей

1) класс, который будет в себе хранить данные о работе с файлом и итераторами "движения по нему"

2) класс, который будет подаваться на вход первому классу, который знает о `CDataCompact`, знает его размер и умеет с ним работать (распорсивать)

2.1) а если понадобится, то такой же класс для `CDataFull`

В результате получился вот такой каркас:

```
template<typename IData>
class CExtractorIterator : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, IData>
{
    friend class IExtractor;

private:
    _i64    m_recordIndex;

private:
    CExtractorIterator(const _i64 recordIndex);

public:
    CExtractorIterator(const CExtractorIterator &it);

    bool                                    operator!=(CExtractorIterator const& other) const;
    bool                                    operator==(CExtractorIterator const& other) const;
    typename CExtractorIterator::reference  operator*() const;
    CExtractorIterator&                     operator++();
};

template<typename IData>
CExtractorIterator<IData>::CExtractorIterator(const _i64 recordIndex)
{
    m_recordIndex = recordIndex;
}

template<typename IData>
CExtractorIterator<IData>::CExtractorIterator(const CExtractorIterator& it)
{
    m_recordIndex = it.m_recordIndex;
}

template<typename IData>
bool CExtractorIterator<IData>::operator!=(CExtractorIterator const& other) const
{
    return m_recordIndex != other.m_recordIndex;
}

template<typename IData>
bool CExtractorIterator<IData>::operator==(CExtractorIterator const& other) const
{
    return m_recordIndex == other.m_recordIndex;
}

template<typename IData>
typename CExtractorIterator<IData>::reference CExtractorIterator<IData>::operator*() const
{
 //   return *p; тут извлечение данных из буфера
}

template<typename IData>
CExtractorIterator<IData> &CExtractorIterator<IData>::operator++()
{
    // тут считывание нового куска файла, если происходит выход за буфер
    m_recordIndex++;
    return *this;
}


template<class IExtractor, class IData>
class CExtractor
{
public:
    typedef CExtractorIterator<IData> iterator;
    typedef CExtractorIterator<const IData> const_iterator;

protected:
    const _i64      m_recordsAmount = 1000000;

    std::ifstream   m_file;
    _i64            m_fileSize = 0;

    char*           m_fileBuffer = nullptr;
    _i64            m_fileBufferSize = 0;

    _i64            m_recordsMaxAmount = 0;

public:
    CExtractor();
    ~CExtractor();

    bool    open(const std::wstring& path);
    void    close();

    iterator        begin();
    const_iterator  begin() const;

    iterator        end();
    const_iterator  end() const;
};

template<class IExtractor, class IData>
CExtractor<IExtractor, IData>::CExtractor
()
{}

template<class IExtractor, class IData>
CExtractor<IExtractor, IData>::~CExtractor
()
{
    close();
}

// открыть файл
template<class IExtractor, class IData>
bool
CExtractor<IExtractor, IData>::open
(const std::wstring& path)
{
    // закрыть старый файл
    close();

    // считать данные об IP из файла
    m_file.open(path, std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);

    // определить размер файла
    m_fileSize = m_file.tellg();

    // выставить указатель файла на начало
    m_file.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);

    // выделить память под файловый буфер
    m_fileBufferSize = m_recordsAmount * IExtractor::size();
    m_fileBuffer = new char[m_fileBufferSize];

    // вычислить кол-во записей в файле
    m_recordsMaxAmount = m_fileSize / IExtractor::size();

    return true;
}

// закрыть файл
template<class IExtractor, class IData>
void
CExtractor<IExtractor, IData>::close
()
{
    // освободить память
    if (m_fileBuffer != nullptr)
    {
        delete[] m_fileBuffer;
        m_fileBuffer = nullptr;

        m_fileBufferSize = 0;
    }

    // закрыть файл
    m_file.close();
}

template<class IExtractor, class IData>
CExtractor<IExtractor, IData>::iterator
CExtractor<IExtractor, IData>::begin
()
{
    return iterator(0);
}


template<class IExtractor, class IData>
CExtractor<IExtractor, IData>::const_iterator
CExtractor<IExtractor, IData>::begin() const
{
    return const_iterator(0);
}

template<class IExtractor, class IData>
CExtractor<IExtractor, IData>::iterator
CExtractor<IExtractor, IData>::end()
{
    return const_iterator(m_recordsMaxAmount);
}

template<class IExtractor, class IData>
CExtractor<IExtractor, IData>::const_iterator
CExtractor<IExtractor, IData>::end() const
{
    return const_iterator(m_recordsMaxAmount);
}
```

И использовать можно так:

```
CExtractor<CDataCompactParser, CDataCompact> extractor(path);
```

где `CDataCompact` - просто структура, а `CDataCompactParser` класс с набором статических функций, который умеет работать (знает размер, распарсивает и т.д.) со структурой `CDataCompact`

Но теперь встал вопрос - а насколько я большого монстра то придумываю, может и излишним он выходит

1) если `CDataCompactParser` знает о `CDataCompact`, то пусть он имеет метод для выдачи этого типа, тогда в шаблоне можно избавиться от второго параметры, учитывая, что если во второй параметр ввести не ту структуру, все рухнет, а значит надо защититься от этого

2) где данные о файле должны храниться - в `CExtractor` или в `CExtractorIterator` и не лучше ли в итератор передавать тогда указатель на класс?

В общем какие в моей идее есть недостатки/ужасные недостатки/отвратительные недостатки?

Comment: Мне кажется, вы не ту абстракцию начали реализовывать. Итераторы могут быть полезны, когда потом к ним применять разные стандартные алгоритмы. А у вас вроде как надо просто обработать данные подряд. Хватило бы единственного колбека для обработки. И да, стоит заменить работу с файлом обратно на WinAPI.

Comment: Что-то мне кажется на первый взгляд, что в этой ситуации лучше иметь вазовый (вероятно, абстрактный) класс, который умеет читать свои данные из файла, и пара наследников, которые эти считанные данные умеют обрабатывать. Т.е. мне не кажется хорошей идеей обвязка чтения файла итераторами...

Answer (score 0):

получился вот такой код

```
template <typename IData>
class CExtractor;

template <typename IData>
class CExtractorIterator : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, IData>
{
    friend class CExtractor<IData>;

protected:
    CExtractor<IData>*  m_extractor;
    _i64                m_recordIndex;

protected:
    CExtractorIterator(CExtractor<IData>* extractor, const _i64 recordIndex);

public:
    CExtractorIterator(const CExtractorIterator &it);

    bool                operator!=(CExtractorIterator const& other) const;
    bool                operator==(CExtractorIterator const& other) const;
    CExtractorIterator& operator++();
    typename CExtractorIterator::reference  operator*() const;

    _i64                pos() const;
};

template <typename IData>
CExtractorIterator<IData>::CExtractorIterator
(CExtractor<IData>* extractor, const _i64 recordIndex)
{
    m_recordIndex = recordIndex;
    m_extractor = extractor;
}

template <typename IData>
CExtractorIterator<IData>::CExtractorIterator
(const CExtractorIterator& other)
{
    m_recordIndex = other.m_recordIndex;
    m_extractor = other.m_extractor;
}

template <typename IData>
bool
CExtractorIterator<IData>::operator!=
(CExtractorIterator const& other) const
{
    return m_recordIndex != other.m_recordIndex;
}

template <typename IData>
bool
CExtractorIterator<IData>::operator==
(CExtractorIterator const& other) const
{
    return m_recordIndex == other.m_recordIndex;
}

template <typename IData>
CExtractorIterator<IData>&
CExtractorIterator<IData>::operator++()
{
    m_recordIndex++;

    m_extractor->m_localRecordIndex++;

    if (m_extractor->m_localRecordIndex >= m_extractor->m_readedRecords)
    {
        std::cout << m_recordIndex << "\r";
        m_extractor->update();
    }

    return *this;
}

template <typename IData>
typename CExtractorIterator<IData>::reference
CExtractorIterator<IData>::operator*() const
{
    return *(IData*)(m_extractor->m_fileBuffer + sizeof(IData) * m_extractor->m_localRecordIndex);
}

template <typename IData>
_i64
CExtractorIterator<IData>::pos() const
{
    return m_recordIndex;
}


/* ----------------------------------------------------------------- */

template <typename IData>
class CExtractor
{
public:
    typedef CExtractorIterator<IData>       iterator;
    typedef CExtractorIterator<const IData> const_iterator;

public:
    const _i64      m_recordsInBuffer = 1000000;

    std::ifstream   m_file;
    _i64            m_fileSize = 0;

    char*           m_fileBuffer = nullptr;
    _i64            m_fileBufferSize = 0;

    _i64            m_recordsInFile = 0;
    _i64            m_readedRecords = 0;

    _i64            m_localRecordIndex;

protected:
public:
    void    update();

public:
    CExtractor(const std::wstring& path = L"");
    ~CExtractor();

    bool    open(const std::wstring& path);
    void    close();

    _i64    size() const;

    iterator        begin();
    iterator        end();

    const_iterator  cbegin() const;
    const_iterator  cend() const;
};

template <typename IData>
CExtractor<IData>::CExtractor
(const std::wstring& path)
{
    if (path.size() > 0)
        open(path);
}

template <typename IData>
CExtractor<IData>::~CExtractor
()
{
    close();
}

// открыть файл
template <typename IData>
bool
CExtractor<IData>::open
(const std::wstring& path)
{
    // закрыть старый файл
    close();

    // считать данные об IP из файла
    m_file.open(path, std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);

    // определить размер файла
    m_fileSize = m_file.tellg();

    // выставить указатель файла на начало
    m_file.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);

    // выделить память под файловый буфер
    m_fileBufferSize = m_recordsInBuffer * sizeof(IData);
    m_fileBuffer = new char[m_fileBufferSize];

    // вычислить кол-во записей в файле
    m_recordsInFile = m_fileSize / sizeof(IData);

    // считать первый блок
    update();

    return true;
}

// закрыть файл
template <typename IData>
void
CExtractor<IData>::close
()
{
    // освободить память
    if (m_fileBuffer != nullptr)
    {
        delete[] m_fileBuffer;
        m_fileBuffer = nullptr;

        m_fileBufferSize = 0;
    }

    // закрыть файл
    m_file.close();
}

// обновить буфер
template <typename IData>
void
CExtractor<IData>::update
()
{
    // считать данные из файла в буфер
    m_file.read(m_fileBuffer, m_fileBufferSize);

    m_readedRecords = m_file.gcount() / sizeof(IData);

    m_localRecordIndex = 0;
}

// получить кол-во записей в файле
template <typename IData>
_i64
CExtractor<IData>::size
() const
{
    return m_recordsInFile;
}

template<class IData>
CExtractorIterator<IData>
CExtractor<IData>::begin
()
{
    return iterator(this, 0);
}

template<class IData>
CExtractorIterator<IData>
CExtractor<IData>::end
()
{
    return iterator(this, m_recordsInFile);
}

template<class IData>
CExtractorIterator<const IData>
CExtractor<IData>::cbegin() const
{
    return const_iterator(this, 0);
}

template<class IData>
CExtractorIterator<const IData>
CExtractor<IData>::cend() const
{
    return const_iterator(this, m_recordsInFile);
}
```

Оказалось, что не надо указывать второй класс в шаблон, который отвечал для преобразования IData в другой тип

Достаточно просто было для IData переопределить операцию преобразования в нужный тип
`operator IData2() const`

**Возникло несколько проблем только, решить которые пока не могу:**

1. почему то не удается использовать переопределённый тип `iterator`

чтобы вместо

```
template<class IData>
CExtractorIterator<const IData>
CExtractor<IData>::cend() const
{
    return const_iterator(this, m_recordsInFile);
}
```

было

```
template<class IData>
CExtractor<IData>::const_iterator
CExtractor<IData>::cend() const
{
    return const_iterator(this, m_recordsInFile);
}
```

2. Вроде как в классе CExtractorIterator я объявил `friend class CExtractor<IData>;`, но не получается получить доступ к защищенным методам и членам класса `CExtractor`(например, к функции `update`), так что пришлось все сделать публичным, что не очень то хорошо

Answer (score 0):

Исправил все сложности, которые возникли до этого, теперь код стал таким:

```
template <typename IData>
class CExtractor;

template <typename IData>
class CExtractorIterator : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, IData>
{
    friend class CExtractor<IData>;

protected:
    CExtractor<IData>*  m_extractor;
    _i64                m_recordIndex;

protected:
    CExtractorIterator(CExtractor<IData>* extractor, const _i64 recordIndex);

public:
    CExtractorIterator(const CExtractorIterator &it);

    bool                operator!=(CExtractorIterator const& other) const;
    bool                operator==(CExtractorIterator const& other) const;
    CExtractorIterator& operator++();
    typename CExtractorIterator::reference  operator*() const;

    _i64                pos() const;
};

template <typename IData>
CExtractorIterator<IData>::CExtractorIterator
(CExtractor<IData>* extractor, const _i64 recordIndex)
{
    m_recordIndex = recordIndex;
    m_extractor = extractor;
}

template <typename IData>
CExtractorIterator<IData>::CExtractorIterator
(const CExtractorIterator& other)
{
    m_recordIndex = other.m_recordIndex;
    m_extractor = other.m_extractor;
}

template <typename IData>
bool
CExtractorIterator<IData>::operator!=
(CExtractorIterator const& other) const
{
    return m_recordIndex != other.m_recordIndex;
}

template <typename IData>
bool
CExtractorIterator<IData>::operator==
(CExtractorIterator const& other) const
{
    return m_recordIndex == other.m_recordIndex;
}

template <typename IData>
CExtractorIterator<IData>&
CExtractorIterator<IData>::operator++()
{
    m_recordIndex++;

    m_extractor->m_localRecordIndex++;

    if (m_extractor->m_localRecordIndex >= m_extractor->m_readedRecords)
    {
        std::cout << m_recordIndex << "\r";
        m_extractor->update();
    }

    return *this;
}

template <typename IData>
typename CExtractorIterator<IData>::reference
CExtractorIterator<IData>::operator*() const
{
    return *(IData*)(m_extractor->m_fileBuffer + sizeof(IData) * m_extractor->m_localRecordIndex);
}

template <typename IData>
_i64
CExtractorIterator<IData>::pos() const
{
    return m_recordIndex;
}


/* ----------------------------------------------------------------- */

template <typename IData>
class CExtractor
{
    friend class CExtractorIterator<IData>;
    friend class CExtractorIterator<const IData>;

public:
    typedef CExtractorIterator<IData>       iterator;
    typedef CExtractorIterator<const IData> const_iterator;

protected:
    const _i64      m_recordsInBuffer = 1000000;

    std::ifstream   m_file;
    _i64            m_fileSize = 0;

    char*           m_fileBuffer = nullptr;
    _i64            m_fileBufferSize = 0;

    _i64            m_recordsInFile = 0;
    _i64            m_readedRecords = 0;

    _i64            m_localRecordIndex;

protected:
    void    update();

public:
    CExtractor(const std::wstring& path = L"");
    ~CExtractor();

    bool    open(const std::wstring& path);
    void    close();

    _i64    size() const;

    iterator        begin();
    iterator        end();

    const_iterator  cbegin() const;
    const_iterator  cend() const;
};

template <typename IData>
CExtractor<IData>::CExtractor
(const std::wstring& path)
{
    if (path.size() > 0)
        open(path);
}

template <typename IData>
CExtractor<IData>::~CExtractor
()
{
    close();
}

// открыть файл
template <typename IData>
bool
CExtractor<IData>::open
(const std::wstring& path)
{
    // закрыть старый файл
    close();

    // считать данные об IP из файла
    m_file.open(path, std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);

    // определить размер файла
    m_fileSize = m_file.tellg();

    // выставить указатель файла на начало
    m_file.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);

    // выделить память под файловый буфер
    m_fileBufferSize = m_recordsInBuffer * sizeof(IData);
    m_fileBuffer = new char[m_fileBufferSize];

    // вычислить кол-во записей в файле
    m_recordsInFile = m_fileSize / sizeof(IData);

    // считать первый блок
    update();

    return true;
}

// закрыть файл
template <typename IData>
void
CExtractor<IData>::close
()
{
    // освободить память
    if (m_fileBuffer != nullptr)
    {
        delete[] m_fileBuffer;
        m_fileBuffer = nullptr;

        m_fileBufferSize = 0;
    }

    // закрыть файл
    m_file.close();
}

// обновить буфер
template <typename IData>
void
CExtractor<IData>::update
()
{
    // считать данные из файла в буфер
    m_file.read(m_fileBuffer, m_fileBufferSize);

    m_readedRecords = m_file.gcount() / sizeof(IData);

    m_localRecordIndex = 0;
}

// получить кол-во записей в файле
template <typename IData>
_i64
CExtractor<IData>::size
() const
{
    return m_recordsInFile;
}

template<class IData>
typename CExtractor<IData>::iterator
CExtractor<IData>::begin
()
{
    return iterator(this, 0);
}

template<class IData>
typename CExtractor<IData>::iterator
CExtractor<IData>::end
()
{
    return iterator(this, m_recordsInFile);
}

template<class IData>
typename CExtractor<IData>::const_iterator
CExtractor<IData>::cbegin() const
{
    return const_iterator(this, 0);
}

template<class IData>
typename CExtractor<IData>::const_iterator
CExtractor<IData>::cend() const
{
    return const_iterator(this, m_recordsInFile);
}
```

появился новый вопрос - почему друзей пришлось указать в обоих классах, но это уже не так принципиально и можно постараться будет понять :)